# If entity exists return a value in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have Two tables "Customer" table and "Blacklist" customer table.
When i blacklist a customer i put the customerid as a foreign key to Blacklist table.

What i want to do is I need to find the Customer by "CusId" in the Customer Table.
I retrieve Name,Area,Telephone,Email from Customer table. When i retrive it, it should also check whether the customer id is in the black list customer table too.
depending on the existance it should pass a boolean value.

Final result should have total 5 columns.
(Name,Area,Telephone,Email,IsBlacklist).

Please help me to code this Entity Framework C#.
Thanks in advance.

```
Customer
---------
(CusId,Name,Telephone,Email)

Blacklist
---------
(CusId)
```

Comment: please provide your models (customer and blacklist class),maybe relevant code and your attempt (if there is any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use navigation property of `blacklist`, that is exist on customer :

```
var customer = Customer.Select(u => new
{
    u.Name,
    u.Area,
    u.Telephone,
    u.Email,
    Blacklist = u.Blacklist.Any()
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: +1: This would be the correct way. (Small correction: It's `Select` in LINQ.)

Answer (score 1):

To start you off:

```
var customer =
    from c in Customer
    where c.CusId == yourId
    select new 
    {
        c.Name, c.Area, c.Telephone, c.Email, 
        IsBlacklist = Blacklist.Any(b => b.CusId == yourId)
    };
```